Constant Voltage and Constant Current on LED driver
I want to build a low-power LED driver for three LEDs, each consuming 0.5 W, powered by a single-cell Li-ion battery
However, when I searched the internet about LED drivers, I found many references to constant voltage and constant current. In my case, are these necessary? If not, why?

Yes I would say they are necessary. LEDs or diodes in general have a exponential relationship between voltage and current in the device. this means that small changes in voltage can result in huge changes in current.
So you usually make a constant current source and let the voltage settle to whatever is necessary. Simply speaking.

If you use a constant-voltage supply, a resistor is necessary to control the current fed to the LED, preventing excessive current that could damage the LED. However, if the current is high, the resistor might waste energy. For this reason, the most efficient LED drivers are constant-current types, as they provide precise control over the power delivered to the LED, enhancing efficiency.

If your power supply is constant voltage, as most general purpose supplies are, then you are responsible for regulating current in the LEDs yourself. That can be done in a few different ways, the most common being a single resistor. The thinking goes like this: all LEDs are diodes, which have the interesting property of deciding for themselves what voltage they will develop across themselves when current flows through them, and that voltage will remain more or less constant even as current through them changes.
You've no doubt heard that red LEDs develop about 1.7V, green are closer to 2V, and blue/white ones could be 3V or 4V, or somewhere in between depending on the model. That means you can't just apply 5V across a 3.5V LED, because so much current will flow as the battery attempts to keep the voltage at 5V, while the LED insists that it be 3.5V, and something breaks, usually the LED.
So with a constant voltage supply, you must provide some means of "bridging the voltage gap", a unit to dispense with the excess voltage and its attendant excess energy. That can be a simple resistance:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With a supply of \$V_S=5V\$, and an LED which develops forward voltage \$V_F=3.5V\$, and your target LED current is \$I=100mA\$, the value of R1 is calculated using Ohm's law:
$$ R_1 = \frac{V_S - V_F}{I} = \frac{5V - 3.5V}{100mA} = 15\Omega $$
This works well if the voltage source is constant, and significantly greater than \$V_F\$, but any fluctuation, such as you might observe as a cell discharges from 4.2V to 3.6V will cause current \$I\$ to vary somewhat, as you can see on ammeter AM2 above right. You may have noticed that you must use a voltage source at least a volt or so higher than your LED voltage. This is going to be a big issue when the cell isn't fully charged, with only 4V or lower across it.
You can replace the resistor with something more adaptive, able to limit current to whatever amount you desire, say 100mA, but with much more precision, and with the ability to adjust its own effective resistance to whatever value is required to pass exactly 100mA, regardless of supply voltage fluctuations. Such a device would be called a "linear current regulator", which isn't the same as constant current power supply, and I mention it only for completeness.
Both of the above solutions will waste power. In my examples, the resistor or regulator will have 1.5V across it, while passing 100mA, so the resistor/regulator will dissipate power \$P_R\$:
$$ P_R = I00mA \times 1.5V = 0.15W $$
Power received by the LED will be \$P_{LED}\$:
$$ P_{LED} =100mA \times 3.5V = 0.35W $$
Power efficiency \$Q\$ will be low:
$$ Q = \frac{0.35W}{0.15W + 0.35W} = 70\% $$
Only 70% of the power delivered from the 5V source will end up reaching the LED, the rest is wasted as heat. For whatever voltages and current your final system will use, you would need to perform similar calculations to ensure that you aren't exceeding power ratings for the resistor or regulator.
Some LEDs have built-in resistors, and as such they are designed and intended to be powered from a constant voltage supply, often 12V or 24V. If your own LEDs are like that, then they would still work with a constant current supply, but the intent of such LEDs is to avoid the need for that, and to use a much more ubiquitous constant voltage one instead.
A constant current supply can be either "linear" or "switching" (switch-mode). I already demonstrated the problem with linear ones above; they tend to have low efficiency. The switching variety does not dispense with excess voltage in the same way. Like their "linear current regulator" cousins, a switching current regulator will apply exactly the right voltage across the LED (or string of LEDs) needed to pass exactly the right current, but it does this without employing a resistor to "throw away" excess energy. Consequently, switch-mode constant current supplies can achieve much better efficiency anywhere from 80% to 95% depending on how much you spend on them. If you intend to maximise running time when powering the system from a battery/cell, then go for a switching constant current supply.
If you have a string of LEDs which require (in total) a higher voltage than your cell produces (3.6V at worst), then you are forced to use a switching constant-current supply. Linear regulators cannot "boost" voltage, but some (many?) switch-mode ones can.
In fact, constant current supplies alleviate so many issues, that I would always advise their use over constant voltage supplies, unless cost is a concern. I haven't done any research on currently available supplies, so I can't recommend any particular model, but switch-mode constant current is the way to go in my opinion, especially when your cell is only 3.6V.
